# Laragon : Error message : (include_path='.;C:/laragon/etc/php/pear') in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, onedrive, laragon, wwwroot, wamp64

I have two machine (LapTop & DeskTop),
so I use WWW in a cloud OneDrive folder,
pro easier synchronisation.

Strangely I didn't had any trouble until june,
when I installed the last Windows 10 2019 Creator Update…
I formatted my C drive and installed the update,
but the problem is that I use an other drive of 1To pro my OneDrive files (with 1To subscription),
and of course in properties,
the authorisation using my login who is linked to my Hotmail,
was not recognized,
and shown as a long number
I changed all authorisation with the actual login.

But now when I launch a php page on local host, I get this message :

**Laragon**

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'I:/Users/nemza/OneDrive/www/taocodex/templates/ueb/wp/converter/WP_converter_18_columns.php' (include_path='.;C:/laragon/etc/php/pear') in Unknown on line 0
```

**wamp64 :**

```
( ! ) FWarning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

( ! ) Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'I:/Users/nemza/OneDrive/www/index.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in Unknown on line 0
```

I can't find a solution on Google, and I know that before it was working, I don’t have trouble with HTML files,
any solution ?
Don’t tell & answer me to use www in Laragon folder, I don’t want to do this.

Few day after,
I have formated the I:\ drive, and reinstalled and downloaded the OneDrive files.
But I still have this problem ?

If use i:\users\nemza\www it's working fine,
if use i:\users\nemza\OneDrive\www, not.

{Image refused because not 10 of reputation.}

What are the "security setting" that I should use ?
What is the problem ?
I written in [Laragon](https://forum.laragon.org/topic/1630/error-message-include_path-c-laragon-etc-php-pear-in-unknown-on-line-0/3) forum without any response !
Any advice please ?

Can someone help please ?
Thank you, good day.

1. Changed security settings in properties.
2. Reinstalled application with administrator power.
3. Formatted the drive.
4. added path ".;C:\laragon\etc\php\pear" & "C:\laragon\etc\php\pear" in System & User Environment variable, with no success.
5. Asked a friend to install Laragon, and set WWW in OneDrive, exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

- If you don't want to use default www folder of laragon try any other folder outside Onedrive. you can do c:/www.
- If you want to use Onedrive for syncing purposes i do recommend to use git instead
- If you want to collaborate with somebody i do recommend to use following addons of VScode [Live Share](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MS-vsliveshare.vsliveshare) or [Remote Development](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack) (Depends on use case)

I wrote above based on my experience and reasons why i wanted to use Onedrive for my code projects, even if you find a way to make it work again with Onedrive i do not recommend using it for servers, code or basically any project with multiple files that are being updated frequently.

I had cases of syncing issues where files were not uploaded fully on the server not showing any signs of errors, or onedrive corrupting files inside my local environment.

No issues so far for regular use, like archiving, syncing images or working with office documents.